# Doob-Dynkin Lemma for Stopped Sigma Field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains

Suppose that $X_{0},X_{1},\ldots$ is a sequence of real-valued random variables.  Let $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma(X_{0},\ldots,X_{n})$.  The Doob-Dynkin lemma says that any $Y$ that is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable can be written as $Y=g(X_{0},\ldots, X_{n})$ for $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable (with respect to the Borel sigma fields).  This lemma is sometimes used to interpret $\mathbb{E}(Y| \mathcal{F}_{n})$ as either a random variable or a measurable function $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (as in the second paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation).

If $N$ is a stopping time, we sometimes condition on $\mathcal{F}_{N}$, as in the strong markov property.  Is there a version of the Doob-Dynkin lemma for $\mathcal{F}_{N}$?  My intuition is that an $\mathcal{F}_{N}$-measurable random variable should be some kind of measurable function of the information $(N=n,X_{0}=x_{0},\ldots,X_{n}=x_{n})$.

Comment: The stopped version is certainly something like this; $Y\in F_N$ if and only if there exist functions $g_n:\Bbb R^{n+1}\to \Bbb R$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $Y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\bf 1}(N=n) g(X_0,\dots,X_n).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Introduction

I'll be working in the discrete time setting, which seems to be the case in OP's question. Define $1_{S}$ as the indicator function of a set $S$.

Let's recall what the definition of $\mathcal F_N$ is : A set $A \in \mathcal F$ (which is the sigma-algebra for the probability space on which the $X_i$ are defined) belongs in $\mathcal F_N$ if and only if , for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have that $A \cap \{N = n\} \in \mathcal F_n$.

We also recall a simple fact : a set $B$ is contained in a sigma-algebra $\mathcal G$ if and only if $1_B$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal G$.

In other words, we should have , for all $n \in \mathbb N$ that $1_{A \cap \{N = n\}}$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable.

Using the Doob-Dynkin lemma for the case that we do know, this occurs if and only if $1_{A \cap \{N = n\}} = g(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$ (almost surely) for some function $g : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$.

Note that $1_{A \cap \{N = n\}} = 1_{A} 1_{\{N=n\}}$ and ,*if we assume that $N$ is a.s. finite*, then it is true that $1_{A} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{A}1_{\{N = n\}}$ (since the exceptional set is contained in $\{N = \infty\}$ , which has measure zero).

But then, using the property of indicators,
$$
1_A1_{\{N = n\}} = 1_{\{N = n\}}(1_{A} 1_{\{N =n\}}) = 1_{\{N = n\}} g(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)
$$

and using countable additivity and monotonicity of the underlying probability measure , the union  of the null sets on which the above don't hold for a particular $n$, has probability zero.

In particular, we arrive at the following statement.

> For $A \in \mathcal F$, $1_A$ is $\mathcal F_N$ measurable for an a.s. finite stopping time $N$ if and only if there exist $g_n : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ such that
> $$
> 1_A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N=n\}}g_n(X_0,...,X_n)
> $$
> almost surely.

---

##### Statement of our Doob-Dynkin Lemma

At this point, we are ready to mock the Doob-Dynkin lemma proof and prove the following :

> Let $X_i$ be a sequence of random variables, $N$ be an a.s. finite stopping time for the filtration generated by the $X_i$, and $\mathcal F_N$ the associated stopped filtration. A random variable $Y$ is $\mathcal F_N$ measurable if and only if there exist Borel measurable functions $g_n : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ such that $$
> Y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{N=n\}}g_n(X_0,...,X_n)
> $$
> almost surely.

Proof : We'll mock the Wikipedia proof, pretty much line-for-line. You can try this yourself, but I'm going to edit this in because it's essential to my answer and I'd like it to be present in the post. (Note : I'd have absolutely loved to use the monotone class theorem for functions, but I'm not going to. Instead, for this I'll redirect you [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2019/10/27/the-functional-monotone-class-theorem/) to see the result that you will need to use, and it's one that will benefit you for future usage).

###### Simple random variables

So for random variables of the form $Y= 1_A$ for $A \in \mathcal F_N$, we are already done. Let's now consider a *simple* random variable i.e. one that is of the form $Y = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i1_{A_i}$ where $c_i$ are real constants and $A_i,i=1,...,m \in \mathcal F_N$ is a partition of the sample space. How does the lemma work here?

Well, for each $i$, we know that $1_{A_i} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N = n\}}g^i_n(X_0,...,X_n)$ for Borel measurable $g^i_n$. By exchanging the finite and infinite summation, we obtain :
$$
Y= \sum_{i=1}^m c_i \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N=n\}}g^i_n(X_0,...,X_n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N=n\}}\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^m c_i g^i_n(X_0,...,X_n)}
$$

where the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ part is a finite sum of Borel functions, hence Borel itself. Thus, we are done for simple functions.

###### Positive random variables

Next, we use the following result : any non-negative (not necessarily bounded) measurable random variable $Y$ is the pointwise a.s. limit of an a.s. *non-decreasing* sequence of simple random variables $Y_k$.

Suppose that $Y_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N=n\}} g^k_n(X_0,...,X_n)$ for some $g^k_n$ Borel. What we know, is that $Y = \lim_{k \to \infty} Y_k$ a.s.

Now, suppose we could prove that all the equalities in :
$$
Y =^{(1)} \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{N=n\}} g^k_n(X_0,...,X_n) =^{(2)}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty [\lim_{k \to \infty} 1_{\{N=n\}} g^k_n(X_0,...,X_n)] \\ =^{(3)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  1_{\{N=n\}}\left[\color{green}{\lim_{k \to \infty} g^k_n(X_0,...,X_n)}\right]
$$

held true a.s. and concerned well-defined quantities , we are done. Equality $1$ follows by substituting for $Y_k$ in the formula $Y = \lim_{k \to \infty} Y_k$.

Equality $2$ will follow from the *monotone convergence theorem* , so let's prove it. If we fix an $\omega$ in the sample space for which the $Y_k$ are non-decreasing and $N(\omega) = n <\infty$ then  $Y_k(\omega)$ increasing implies that the sequence $g^k_n(X_0(\omega),...,X_n(\omega))$ is non-negative and increasing in $k$, and obviously that $1_{N(\omega)=n}g^k_n(X_0(\omega),...,X_n(\omega))$ is increasing in $k$. Thus, $1_{N=n}g^k_n(X_0,...,X_n)$ is non-negative a.s. increasing in $k$ for all $n$ : which means the monotone convergence theorem applies and $2$ is proved.

Equality $3$ is obvious, but we already discussed above that $g_n^k(X_0,...,X_n)$ are non-negative increasing in $k$, and any non-negative increasing sequence has a limit in $\overline{\mathbb R}$. It is well known that the limit is a well defined Borel measurable function. Thus, the result holds for all positive random variables $Y$.

###### General case

Write , for a  general random variable $Y$, the decomposition $Y = Y^+ - Y^-$ where $Y^+ = \max\{Y,0\}$ and $Y^- = \max\{-Y,0\}$. Each of the random variables $Y^+$ and $Y^-$ is a non-negative random variable, hence by the above demonstration can be written in the desired form. As $Y$ is just a difference of these, using an argument analogous to the exchange of the finite-infinite summation performed earlier, we conclude that $Y$ can be written in the form desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you very much , I hope to be of more service in the future. I'd imagine that , under some continuity-type assumptions on the stochastic process $X_t$ and/or continuity conditions (the "usual" conditions) on the filtration $\mathcal F_t$, this result can be extended , in a perhaps different manner, to continuous time as well.